# moving a set of items that contains a clip-rect attribute

Tags: raphael

I have a set containing image objects. Each object is cropped using the 'clip-rect' attribute.
when I transform the entire set

```
   allframes.transform("t50,0")
```

all the images move 50 pixels to the right, but the clip-rect stays in place.
how can I get the clip-rect attributes to transform with the entire set?

I am working on this for hours and I am drawing blanks.
I did come up with an inefficient solution:

When I first create the images and crop them, I create rectangles with the attributes of the crop, and push them into the set. when I transform the set, the rectangles move too, and then I reset the attributes on the clip-rect so it matches the getBBox of the corresponding rectangles. it worked for a while but now the code became too complicated for that.

Is there any way to move 'clip-rect' relative to their position?

Here is an illustration of my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/28Fcn/

the yellow square is the same size as the other squares but it is cropped.
when I transform the entire set, all the elements move but the crop stays in place.
click on the rectangles and see.

this is my solution which is not ideal
http://jsfiddle.net/PgK6w/

any ideas?

Comment: I suspect your solution may be the best for the time. I think you may need to get svg groups (as opposed to sets) working for it, which Raphael doesn't support (there may be a plugin for it, you could test), so I'm not sure there is any clean solutuon. You could probably simplify your solution so it looks a bit tidier, but I think the solution is ok.